# OpportunityAccessLevel

Tags: opportunity-teams

I would like to edit 'Opportunity Access' field picklist in Opty Teams objects and I would like to give the users to give only read only access to the opty which is being shared with the opportunity team members. Can you please help.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Create a new Profile, In Standard Object Permissions Give read permission to opportunity and assign Profile to Opportunity Team.